# package android.support.design.widget does not exist after refactor dependencies - Androidx api 28

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

After refactoring dependencies to **androidx** dependencies with android studio I keep getting errors when building. I looks like the application still uses the old depedencies, but I have tried to **clean projekt** and **rebuild project**... nothing helped.

[image: The errors I get when building the project]

Below is the dependencies I use in my application.

```js
    def retrofit_version = "2.4.0"
    def glide_version = "4.3.1"


    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    // Design Support
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
    implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime:2.0.0'
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
    annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

Comment: It can be deeply tricky when refactoring to androidx. Have you tried to check the deep widgets of your application? They have to be deep-changed for example: android.support.v7.deep.widget -> androidx.support.deep.widget